# Using internal speaker while headphone is plugged

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones, speakers

Is there a way to use laptop's internal speaker (temporarily) without unplugging the headphone ?

When I plug the headphone (to be precise , earphone) , the option `Speakers` gets unavailable from the `PavuControl`'s `Output devices`.

OS : Kubuntu 20.04
Pavucontrol : 4.0
Kernel : 5.4

Any help is appreciated.